# Create and update RTF form field

Tags: c#, forms, rtf

I want to achieve the following: update the text in rich text box with a new date at a fixed position.

Lets say I have the following text in: "I'm on vacation from **12-01-2012**, so I will not...". The date in this text needs to change accordingly to the date set in my date picker.

I read the text with the following code which is pretty basic:

```
// Open OOF template
string filename = @"ooftemplate.rtf";
rtbOOFMsg.LoadFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

I think I need to create a RTF form field and update this programmatically. But how do I create/add a RTF form field and how do I update this?

Comment: Could you please provide little bit more information - what do you consider as RTF form field? Should it be a variable like `string` that stores data in *RTF* format together with all formatting?

Comment: I don't know if the term "form field" is correct. I want to keep the formatting. Only the date needs to be updated if the datepicker values changes.

Comment: You can work with `RichTextBox` control using its [Rtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf) property - that will preserve the formatting, but you will need to parse `Rtf` markup alone. Looks like .NET/Visual Studio does not provide 'clever' tools to modify *Rtf* text preserving its formatting (you can resort to utilizing of some *RTF-libraries* for .NET - like [NRTFTree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C)).